# Enclosing Shortcode is acting like self-closing

Tags: shortcode

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, as I rarely use shortcodes, but I can't seem to get the following shortcode to work.

I want it to be an "enclosing" short tag vs. a "self-closing", but its being treated as the latter.

```
[bio_image name="my name" title="my title"]
//image media in post content
[/bio_image]
```

with this functions.php code:

```
function bio_image_func( $atts, $content = null) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'name' => 'employee',
        'title' => 'mastermind',
    ), $atts ) );
    return '<div class="team_photo"><p class="team_title"><span class="name">' . $name . '</span> <span class="title">' . $title . '</span></p>' . $content . '</div>';
}

add_shortcode( 'bio_image ', 'bio_image_func' );
```

produces:

```
<div class="team_photo">
  <p class="team_title">
    <span class="name">my name</span> 
    <span class="title">my title</span>
  </p>
</div>

<img src="my_img_src" ... />

[/bio_image]
```

As you can see, the closing tag is just being printed out.  Any suggestions?

for reference: [the shortcode codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Enclosing_vs_self-closing_shortcodes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space after the shortcode name.

```
add_shortcode( 'bio_image ', 'bio_image_func' );
```

becomes

```
add_shortcode( 'bio_image', 'bio_image_func' );
```

I think WordPress is looking for a closing tag for `bio_image[space]`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: lol sorry! You were right when you said "I'm sure I'm missing something simple" ;)